# Removing some labels(Temples, Restaurents etc) from Google Maps(Google Maps iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am implementing Google Maps in my iOS App. I want to remove certain labels from the map. I want to keep street names but want to remove malls, temples, restuarents etc labels from the map. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

I got it. We can style our maps using Map styles.[check this link](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) Just Style and download the json. Copy the json file into project and set the style like this:

```
if let stylesFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json")
    {
        mMapView.mapStyle = try! GMSMapStyle.init(contentsOfFileURL: stylesFile)
    }
```